# How to DataBind a label or a textBlock in Datagrid Cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datagrid

Hello Guys I hope yall doing great!

I have a problem with a datagrid, I want to put this in datagrid cell for example : "/100" which '100' is the quantity in stock in my database using entity framework, I want to do this so the user tap how many items he wants in a textbox besides the label/textBlock like this :

```
DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=productQuantityStock}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I hope you guys understand what I want to do, and please mind my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code-behind you'll need to bind a context. The context will need a property and a field so the the value can be updated. You should also make use of a method that notifies the view that the property has been updated.

The code behind will look something like this.

```
public class DataContextOfView 
{
    private int _productQuantityStock;
    // Because you'll be working with values of type int you should make it an int
    public int ProductQuantityStock
    {
         get { return _productQuantityStock;}
         set { if(_productQuantityStock != value) 
                { 
                 _productQuantityStock = value
                 // notify that the value of the property has changed.
                 OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProductQuantityStock));
                }
             }
    }
}
```

The code in the view should have a reference to the property

```
DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="0"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductQuantityStock, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: the nameof productQuantityStock does not exist in the current context, how can I fix that ?

Comment: The first letter should be uppercase: productQuantityStock > ProductQuantityStock